# Laravel 4 + CentOS + MSSQL 2012 = error

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, unicode

My laravel 4 app is retrieving data from MSSQL 2012 server. It is working fine on Windows but deployed on CentOS I got the following error:

> Next exception 'Illuminate\Database\QueryException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 4004 General SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server [4004] (severity 16) [(null)]

Checked in the MSSQL error mappings and the exact error is:

> Unicode data in a Unicode-only collation or ntext data can not be sent to clients using DB-Library (z. B. isql) or ODBC version 3.7 or earlier use.

After googling the only thing I found was too low freetds version and I changed it from 4.2 to 7.0 in the etc/freetds.conf - nothing changes. Please advise what might be the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

Did a quickly search and found a couple more things you can do:

```
In /etc/freetds/freetds.conf add these two lines (last two):
[global]
;tds version = 4.2
tds version = 8.0
client charset = UTF-8

You can edit "charset" in php.ini too (but you don't need if you did it previously in freetds.conf):
;Specify client character set..
;If empty or not set the client charset from freetds.comf is used
;This is only used when compiled with FreeTDS
mssql.charset = "UTF-8"
```

Hope this works.

Answer (score 0):

Just like you quoted:

> Unicode data in a Unicode-only collation or ntext data can not be sent
>   to clients using DB-Library (z. B. isql) or ODBC version 3.7 or
>   earlier use.

So you need to upgrade `ODBC` driver **not** `freetds`, in your case you might want to look into upgrading `unix-odbc`.